# Extracting from feedburner feeds?

Tags: feedburner

I want to extract title and image for each item mentioned in http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss feed using PHP ,could anyone please help me out ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

you can try [simplexml_load_string()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_string.asp):
Exemple:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document>
<title>Forty What?</title>
<from>Joe</from>
<to>Jane</to>
<body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
</body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

var_dump($xml);
?>
```